# Use barStyles after setBackgroundImage in UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, appearance

I'm am trying to use the `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent` after styling my `UINavigationBar` with `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics`.

The problem here is, its now always styled and when i set the `barStyle` nothing really happens.

Comment: Using the appearance proxy overrides the appearance of all navigation bars (if you use the [UINavigationBar appearance] proxy). Are you trying to have a mix of styled and default navigation bars in your app?

Comment: Yeah, i got a gallery and want to style it apple like with black bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to set your custom appearance individually for each navigation bar inside your viewcontroller's viewDidLoad rather than using the class proxy:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage...
```

This sounds tedious in the extreme. I'm away from my mac at the moment but it *might* be possible to keep your existing code and use the above method to set the background image to `nil` just for the gallery?